# Can not connect to internet after changing locally administered address

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, mac-address

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address/) to change MAC adresses.

It works when I do this with windows 10 pro on real hardware.

However when I use Windows 10 Pro in a virtual box VM I run into probles. After changing the MAC I cannot connect to the internet anymore.  The network always says no internet access, even after a reboot.

I need to set MAC via locally administered address. How to fix it ?

Comment: What did you change? `locally administered address` is a tad to vague to map to any network terms.  IP address to stattic?  No default gateway? Why did you tag MAC address? ...

Comment: @Hennes, I followed this TUT : http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address

Comment: Hmm. "locally administered adress" is a really weird way of stating "overide the factory managed address with this value".  And changing a MAC address should never be needed. It is (exception, old cable modem era which tied access to a single MAC, but any security which is based on MAC adresses is broken by design).  Still, changing that value to something else which is not yet used anywhere else on the local network should not have broken network access.